# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main_folder'

Tags: python, error-handling, module

Why this code works on one desktop but on the other it does not work and it returns `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main_folder'`?

My code in script.py:

```
from main_folder.folder.function import function
```

File hierchy:

```
-> main_folder
--> folder (contains function.py)
---> subfolder (contains script.py which)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using relative imports? In your case that would mean `from ..folder.function import function`

Comment: It does not work. @Johannes R.

Comment: This reads more like a comment than an answer to me. One of the primary purposes of the question's comment section is to ask for clarification or more details from the asker.